# javascript change string case speed

Tags: javascript, optimization

Which is faster? toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() in javascript?

Comment: Using what typical strings? On what host?

Comment: This is pedantically interesting but if this is just for case-insensitive comparisons...

Comment: This is a perfectly legit question.  I still have to ask, though: Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some [test results](http://justkarp.com/2010/04/20/touppercase-vs-tolowercase/) from major browsers (several months old). It comes to the conclusion that `toLowerCase()` is faster, but there are no insights into *why* provided.

**EDIT:**

I have gone and looked through the WebKit JavaScript source code just out of curiosity. The `.toUpperCase()` and `.toLowerCase()` prototype methods are identical except for some calls to `.toASCIIUpper()`, `.toASCIILower()`, and `Unicode::toUpper()` and `Unicode::toLower()`. Further inspecting the first two methods, I saw that the `.toLowerCase()` function is slightly less complex than the `.toUpperCase()` function.

---

**`.toASCIILower()`** does some simple bit shifting logic:

```
char toASCIILower(char c) { 
    return c | ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') << 5); 
}
```

---

**`.toASCIIUpper()`** is a tad bit more involved:

```
char toASCIIUpper(char c) { 
    return static_cast<char>(c & ~((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') << 5)); 
}
```

---

The static cast and extra bitwise negation (~) in the `.toASCIIUpper()` function, repeated over a million iterations, could perhaps account for its poorer performance.

Now, this is all speculative; I've done no real testing nor have I tried to fully understand these methods, but maybe somebody else can elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Well as per tests conducted this [website](http://justkarp.com/2010/04/20/touppercase-vs-tolowercase/) says

`toLowerCase() is faster than toUpperCase()`

Comment: Who would have thought that there could be such big differences between them. In some cases it is about half the time.

Answer (score 2):

They should be identical. It's *possible* that they could be optimized for the case where all the characters are already upper/lower case, but then it would depend on which case the string is in already, e.g. `'abc'.toLowerCase()` would be faster than `'ABC'.toLowerCase()` because it doesn't have to allocate a new string. I don't know of any implementations that do that though.

Really, the only way to find out is to test both functions with a variety of different strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my test results.

Browser: Google Chrome

OS: Ubuntu

toLowerCase: 19.68 seconds

toUpperCase: 20.71 seconds

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var i=0;
      for (i=0;i<=100000000;i++) { 
        "some string".toUpperCase();
        //"SOME STRING".toLowerCase();
      }
      document.write("done!");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```